# Moment generating function of the sum of uncorrelated random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, correlation, moment-generating-functions

Suppose that $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3 \sim\mathcal{U}_{(0,2\pi)}$  are i.i.d. random variables uniformly distributed on $(0,2\pi)$. We define the random variables:

$c_{12} = \cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$ and $c_{13} = \cos(\theta_1-\theta_3)$.

We note that $c_{12},c_{13}$ are uncorrelated but not indipendent. What we can say about the moment generating function of $c_{12}+c_{13}$? In particular is it true that, in this case:

$$
M_{c_{12}+c_{13}}(t) = \mathbb{E}(e^{t(c_{12}+c_{13})}) = \mathbb{E}(e^{tc_{12}})\mathbb{E}(e^{tc_{13}}) = M_{c_{12}}(t)M_{c_{13}}(t) \mbox{ ?}
$$

**Motivation**

By using the following code in R (which simply uses Monte Carlo simulation), I see that the covariance between $e^{c_{12}}$ and $e^{c_{13}}$ is approximately zero, as the covariance between $c_{12}$ and $c_{13}$.

```
it = 10000
theta1 = runif(it,0,2*pi)
theta2 = runif(it,0,2*pi)
theta3 = runif(it,0,2*pi)
cos12 = cos(theta1-theta2)
cos13 = cos(theta1-theta3)
cos23 = cos(theta2-theta3)
exp12 = exp(cos12)
exp13 = exp(cos13)
exp23 = exp(cos23)
cov(cos12,cos13)
cov(exp12,exp13)
```

Comment: If $\theta_1, \theta_2 \theta_3$ are supposed to be independent you must state that. Without that the question makes no sense.

Comment: @geetha290krm Sorry, of course they are indipendent. I edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a proof, but a computation using *Mathematica* shows that the MGF of $c_{12}$ is $$M_{c_{12}}(t) = \mathcal I_0(t),$$ where $\mathcal I_n(z)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind; and
$$M_{c_{12} + c_{13}}(t) = \mathcal I_0^2(t).$$  So this implies that the relationship $$M_{c_{12} + c_{13}}(t) = M_{c_{12}}(t) M_{c_{13}}(t),$$ since $c_{12}$ and $c_{13}$ are exchangeable and have the same MGF.  Note that because of periodicity,
$$\begin{align}
M_{c_{12}}(t) &= \frac{1}{4\pi^2} \int_{\theta_2 = 0}^{2\pi} \int_{\theta_1 = 0}^{2\pi} e^{t \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2)} \, d\theta_1 \, d\theta_2 \\
&= \frac{1}{4\pi^2} \int_{\theta_2 = 0}^{2\pi} \int_{\psi = -\theta_2}^{2\pi-\theta_2} e^{t \cos(\psi+\theta_2-\theta_2)} \, d\psi \, d\theta_2 \\
&= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\psi = 0}^{\pi} e^{t \cos \psi} \, d\psi,
\end{align}$$
and from [Equation (5)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html), this is $I_0(t)$.

I suspect a substantially similar approach applies for the calculation of the MGF of the sum, but I have not attempted it at this time.

Comment: amazing! I was also trying to understand the form of the moment generating function of $c$ using Mathematica, but I wasn't able to arrive to your result! Thank you.

Comment: @LucaOnnis For your reference, the code I used for the MGF of the sum is `MomentGeneratingFunction[TransformedDistribution[Cos[t1 - t2] + Cos[t1 - t3], {Distributed[t1, UniformDistribution[{0, 2 Pi}]], Distributed[t2, UniformDistribution[{0, 2 Pi}]], Distributed[t3, UniformDistribution[{0, 2 Pi}]]}], t]`

Comment: Thank you @heropup , your answer really simplifies my calculations. :D

Comment: if $M_{c_{12}+c_{13}}(t)$ is the product of the two MGFs, then is it also true that: $M_{\sum_{i<j}^n c_{ij}}(t) = \Pi_{i<j}^{n}M_{c_{ij}}(t)$ ? Because I have to use this property in order to finish the proof, and if it's false.. then I have to understand why in order to correct my proof!

Comment: @LucaOnnis Unfortunately, I believe the answer is no.  Numerical simulation suggests that even in the case of the sum of three cosines, your conjecture does not hold.  You may wish to try running your own simulation, which should show a difference.  It **is** true that the sum $$c_{12} + c_{13} + c_{14} + \cdots + c_{1n}$$ will have an MGF that equals $\mathcal I_0^{n-1}(t)$.  But your case has stronger correlations because for instance $12$ is correlated with $13$ and $23$, so $c_{12} + c_{13} + c_{23}$ will not have MGF equal to $\mathcal I_0^3(t)$.

Comment: ok.. I understand. Although $c_{12}$ and $c_{13}$ are not correlated (?) In general $Cov(c_{ij},c_{kh}) = 0$ for all $i<j$ and $k<h$ with $(i,j)\not = (j,h)$. What do you mean when you say "12 is correlated with 13 and 23"? Is it a form of joint correlation? Sorry for my ignorance! Thank you in advance.

Comment: @LucaOnnis What I meant to say is that in the case of $c_{12}, c_{13}, c_{23}$, there's a kind of three-way correlation that isn't present in $c_{12}, c_{13}, c_{14}$.  In the latter example, the correlation only happens through $\theta_1$, but in the former, it happens through all three variables.  So I suspect this is the reason why the desired relationship does not hold.  I don't have a proof and I think this question needs more investigation, though.